# How to get the bookmark and the index (tableofcontents) with links to each section

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, indexing, bookmarks

I want to make a book without chapters are listed. Have an index (also don't want that chapters are listed in the index) and have the bookmark in the file.pdf. The problem is that I appear twice sections in bookmark. I'm using the package `bookmark` because `hyperref` not supported `\pagenumbering{gobble}` and use  this command to suppress the numbering of pages and start it again after `tableofcontents`.

**What I can do to have the bookmark, where sections appear only once, and get the index (tableofcontents) with links to each section?**

MWE

```
\documentclass{book} 
...
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \chapter*{Presentation} %Presentation of the book
  \bookmark[page=2,level=0]{Presentation} 

\tableofcontents

 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \setcounter{page}{4}

  \chapter*{Test 1}
  \bookmark[page=4,level=0]{Test 1} % places the first bookmarks
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test 1} % places the second bookmarks

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Some remarks:

- `\addcontentsline{toc}{...}{...}` already adds a bookmark.
- I have disabled the page anchors for the pages with `\pagenumbering{gobble}` to avoid conflicts with page destinations for different pages, but the same destination name, because `\thepage` is empty.
- `\pdfbookmark` can be used here that automatically sets an anchor and avoids an explicit page number specification.
- Also I have added `\cleardoublepage`/`\newpage` to ensure the correct page, where `\pagenumbering` or `\pdfbookmark` are executed.

The example file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
  % ...
  \cleardoublepage
  \pdfbookmark{Presentation}{Presentation}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
  \chapter*{Presentation} %Presentation of the book

  \tableofcontents

  \newpage
  \hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \setcounter{page}{4}

  \chapter*{Test 1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test 1} % places the second bookmarks

\end{document}
```